# how to extract the grouped number with search in python?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
x='''
｜   配股次数     ｜      1       ｜ 募资总额(万元) ｜    834582.17     ｜
├────────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┤
｜   增发次数     ｜      1       ｜ 募资总额(万元) ｜    899850.51     ｜
├────────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┤
｜  发转债次数    ｜      1       ｜ 募资总额(万元) ｜    750000.00     ｜
├────────┴───────┴────────┼─────────┤
｜              再融资募资总额(万元)                ｜    2484432.68    ｜
├─────────────────────────┴─────────┤
｜                            ☆派现☆                                  ｜
├────────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┤
｜   派现次数     ｜      14      ｜ 派现总额(万元) ｜    1613873.88    ｜'''


re.search('再融资募资总额\.+(\d+\.\d+)\.+\n',x).group(1)
```

Why i can't get the numbers of `2484432.68` in the string?The group function is used in () properly,i want to get the numbers in the line of `再融资募资总额`.

Comment: If this is a delimited structure, why not just use a simple `.split` for each line on the `|` character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `再融资募资总额\(万元\).*?(\d+\.\d+)` regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> x=u'''
... ｜   配股次数     ｜      1       ｜ 募资总额(万元) ｜    834582.17     ｜
... ├────────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┤
... ｜   增发次数     ｜      1       ｜ 募资总额(万元) ｜    899850.51     ｜
... ├────────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┤
... ｜  发转债次数    ｜      1       ｜ 募资总额(万元) ｜    750000.00     ｜
... ├────────┴───────┴────────┼─────────┤
... ｜              再融资募资总额(万元)                ｜    2484432.68    ｜
... ├─────────────────────────┴─────────┤
... ｜                            ☆派现☆                                  ｜
... ├────────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┤
... ｜   派现次数     ｜      14      ｜ 派现总额(万元) ｜    1613873.88    ｜'''
>>> print re.search(u'再融资募资总额\(万元\).*?(\d+\.\d+)', x).group(1)
2484432.68
```